# Help proving mean and var of independent variables

Tags: statistics

Given $Y{_1},  Y_2....Y_n $independent distributions with means $\mu_1, \mu_2,...\mu_n $ and standard deviations $\sigma_1, \sigma_2, ....\sigma_n$.

Take 
$W = a_1Y_1+a_2Y_2+....+a_nY_n+$

Show that:
$\mu_w = a_1\mu_1+a_2\mu_2+....+a_n\mu_n$

and that

$\sigma^2_w = a^2_1 \sigma^2_1+ a^2_2 \sigma^2_2 +...+ a^2_n \sigma^2_n  $

I get to the point where: 
$\mu_w = 1/n \sum_{i=1}^n a_iY_i$ and I want it to = $\mu_w = \sum_{i=1}^na_n\mu_n$ but now where does the a come from and what does it mean? How can I get these equal, they are almost equal!!

Comment: Please share your efforts towards the solution of the problem, that way it is more likely that you get some help from others.

Comment: @PierreCarre So I know the formula for mean and SD and I get that the mean of W, is just W/n and this formula looks similar to the $\mu_w$ BUT I dont get where the a is coming from

Answer (score 0):

The following are basic properties of expectation and variance: $E(aX+bY)=aEX+bEY$, $var (aX)=a^{2}var(X)$ and $var (X+Y)=var(X)+var(Y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: I am confused about how to use these, since my variables are inside summations, I cannot simply just pull it out and square it? SO for ex - using the second var rule you wrote, I cannot just pull out my a right?

Comment: The first and the third equation in my answer extend (by induction) to any finite sum.

Comment: Thanks so much for your replies -- sorry I am new to stats and a bit confused, could you offer a bit more help?

Comment: Are you familiar with proof by induction?. $E(a_1X_1+a_2X_2+\cdots+a_nX_n)=a_1EX_1+a_2EX_2+\cdots+a_nEX_n$ by induction. Similarly, $var (a_1X_1+a_2X_2+\cdots+a_nX_n)=var(a_1X_1)+var(a_2X_2)+\cdots+var(a_nX_n)=a_1^{2}var(X_1)+\cdots a_n^{2}var(X_n)$.

Comment: Just as a side comment, @mathpun, $E(aX) = a E(X)$ while $var(aX) \not= var(X)$ is a very important fact. (this highlights the fact that $E$ is a linear operator while $var$ is not a linear operator.